# How to get highest number from nested structure

Tags: javascript, algorithm, loops

I have a data structure similar to this ->

```
var prices = [
    {currency: '$', value: 52},
    {currency: '$', value: 139},
    {currency: '$', value: 31},
    {currency: '$', value: 5}
];
```

I want to know the highest price from that data. I know I can loop over the array and collect the data, but what would be the best way of doing it ?

Comment: Any solution will do a loop, maybe internally - but it must be done (the data seems unsorted from the sample, if it is not the case - the answer might be different). **What are you looking for exactly?** (or in other words: define "best way") A javascript short solution? an efficient solution? or theoretical answer how it should be done?

Comment: I just think my current solutions are way too complicated. Maybe they are not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this pretty neat by using `Array.prototype.map` alongside `Math.max`. Since `.map()` returns an *Array*, we can use that to invoke `Math.max` by `Function.prototype.apply`. The result would look like

```
var max = Math.max.apply(null, prices.map(function( entry ) {
    return entry.value;
}));

console.log( max ); // 139
```

---

The above statement equals

```
Math.max( 51, 139, 31, 5 );
```

which would return the same result, we just created it programatically.

Answer (score 6):

Such code :

```
Math.max.apply(Math, prices.map(function(p) {return p.value;}));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
prices.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.value - a.value;
});
```

Then `prices[0].value` will be the highest.

Comment: This will change the order of ``prices``.